# mysql treats the string 'now()' as datetime?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a query that incorrectly constructed to include the function 'now()' as a string:

```
 select Listing.id,Listing.reactivated FROM `listings` AS Listing  WHERE Listing.reactivated < 'now()';
```

but actually this query is able to return correct results with mysql 5.5:

```
|  26662 | 2007-06-04 21:42:51 |
|  26663 | 2007-06-04 21:46:34 |
```

actually, several date functions, even without parentheses work; like 'now' or 'curdate', but a simple, "select 'now()';", will return a string.

Actually, I have noticed this when we upgraded Mysql to MariaDB 10.1, where it stopped working, the result of the above query is a null set, and a warning:

```
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()' |
```

I understand we should fix the queries :), but I would like to ask if anybody knows the reason behind this, when this was changed, and also, if this behavior can be configured?

Comment: It doesn't look like the behavior I am observing; it looks like any datetime is less than `'now()'`. `SELECT (now() + INTERVAL 10 SECOND) < 'now()', (now() + INTERVAL 10 SECOND) > 'now()'` yields (1, 0).

Comment: I find that ANY string literal makes a "valid" comparison with a date field.  `SELECT * FROM mypasswords WHERE expires <  'ndseow'` returns no records.  `SELECT * FROM mypasswords WHERE expires > 'ndseow'` returns all.  If the behavior you saw was correct, it may be coincidence.

Comment: @Uueerdo I did that and got your results, and it also gave the warnings `Truncated incorrect datetime value: 'now()'`.

Comment: It seems like it's converting the datetime to a string, resulting in something like `2016-07-19 01:23:45`, and then comparing that string to `now()`. But the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) says that it's supposed to convert the constant string to a `datetime` and then compare them.

Comment: Thank you, this was all very helpful. I wasn't notice the difference because with both 'now()' and now() we had the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) claims:

> If one of the arguments is a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column and the other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp before the comparison is performed.

But that doesn't seem to be what's happening in this case, so it may be a bug. It appears that it's converting the `DATETIME` to a string, and comparing that with the constant. So if the current datetime is `2016-07-19 15:13:06`, you get the result of:

```
SELECT '2016-07-19 15:13:06' < 'now()';
```

Since digits are lower than letters in the collating sequence, this returns `1`.

I came to this conclusion by trying other strings:

```
SELECT NOW() < '300';
```

This also returns `1`. But if I change it to:

```
SELECT NOW() < '100', NOW() < '!';
```

the results are `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use quotes: `'NOW()'`; simply say `NOW()`.

The former is a *string*, which is not a valid datetime.  (Ditto for `'NOW'` and `'XYZ'`.)